# Change the backspace hotkeys

Tags: shortcut-keys

Currently, to delete one word backwards in Ubuntu, I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Is it possible to reassign deleting one word to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> across all applications?

Also, is it possible to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to deleting everything left of the cursor (on the current line)?

I can't find these shortcuts anywhere, I'm not sure if they're configurable.

Comment: You could [swap left ctrl for left alt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93624/how-do-i-swap-left-ctrl-with-left-alt-on-my-keyboard) if that would be a working solution for you.

Comment: Well I still need those for other things (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a solution to your first problem, other than learning the standard.  It's not clear to me any particular problems you're having with it other than it's not to your liking, not to say that's not a good reason to ask the question!

With that in mind, in order to delete everything before a certain spot in a text file, you can most likely hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the <kbd>Home</kbd> button.  That should select all of the text, so you can now press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, or <kbd>Delete</kbd>, as you prefer, to remove the text.  The opposite can be done with the <kbd>End</kbd> key.

As you pointed out in the comments,  most text manipulation shorcuts are bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, such as copy and paste, while <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> are reserved for other functions.  This is a major difference between [Meta Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) and [Control Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest I'm still hoping to figure out how to switch it. I'm used to the mac hotkeys, and it's just such a hassle switching between the two systems when the hotkeys are different. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: Ahh! Have you tried using the [OSX keyboard mapping](http://askubuntu.com/a/431010/13247)?

Comment: Yeah I was actually excited when I found that, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. Everything was still the old layout.