# How to copy and paste (usb trial of Ubuntu 21.10 on Macbook Pro)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook

Long story short, I am testing out Ubuntu 21.10 through a USB connected to my Macbook Pro laptop (mid-2014). How can I use copy and paste on Ubuntu 21.10? I tried adding the keyboard shortcut (command c/ command v OR control shift c/ control shift v) but haven't had any luck.

At first I thought this was a google suite issue but it doesn't work on any sites. I have at some luck using right click to paste but it is often lagging (i.e., pastes something I copied minutes before). Plus, given I use google suite (Which doesn't allow right click to paste) I'd like to have a working keyboard shortcut.

Any advice you have is appreciated. I'll also note I did look through previous questions but none seemed to speak to this particular issue.

**EDIT: I think I found a solution thanks to this thread**

[How do I remap my Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts to match OSX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368437/how-do-i-remap-my-ubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts-to-match-osx/1385114#1385114)

Settings -> Keyboard -> + (add input source) -> English ([your locale]) -> English (Macintosh).

Make sure you remove all of the other keyboard "input sources" as mine didn't work until I removed those. (I still have customized keyboard shortcuts as "super (command) + c" but I use control on my keyboard.

Comment: I am not familiar with a Mac keyboard, but normally `Ctrl`-`c` is used for copy, `Ctrl`-`x` for cut, and `Ctrl`-`v` for paste.  It shouldn't be necessary to use the `shift` key.  Does the Mac keyboard have a `Ctrl` key?

Comment: @Bovine Yes a mac keyboard does have a Ctrl key. I just tried adding `Ctrl` - `c` and `Ctrl` - `v` under Settings --> keyboard shortcuts --> customize shortcuts --> Custom shortcuts and it doesn't work. Copy seems to work, meaning the text I highlight blinks (quickly changes color) but when I try to paste it is blank.

Comment: I was hoping someone who knew something about Mac's would chime in ... I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.  My only thought is to pull up something like LibreOffice that has copy/paste under the edit menu.  From that you may be able to narrow down whether it is the clipboard that isn't working or whether it is the hotkeys, especially since you believe the `Ctrl`-`c` operation may have worked.

Comment: In LibreOffice I can use the drop down menu to copy and paste things. Meaning I can highlight text, select "Edit copy" and "Edit paste." That works, but the shortcut does not (meaning using `ctrl` - `c`).

Copy and paste also works with my mouse (by right clicking). But I use google docs a lot and they only allow you to copy and paste using keyboard shortcuts. 

I'm really enjoying using Ubuntu but this inability to use the copy and paste shortcuts is a bit of a deal-breaker. SO I am hoping I can find a solution.